# Glossaries in TableOfContents with number

Tags: latex, glossary, glossaries

The title basically explains it. I want to use the package glossaries and include a number in the table of contents, e. g. 8 Glossary instead of Glossary, This code achives this without a number:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\newglossaryentry{Android}
{
    name=Anroid,
    description={Das Betriebssystem der meisten Smartphones.}
}
\makeglossaries
(...)
\printglossary
```

Im just using the default setup on Manjaro wit TexMaker.
Any idea?